# PHP CGI Timeout-s

Tags: cgi, php, timeout, apache2

Добрый день.
Может ли кто-то подсказать по таймаутам с CGI РНР. Есть у меня такой просто скрипт

```
/*
// buffer all upcoming output
ob_start();
echo "test";
// get the size of the output
$size = ob_get_length();

// send headers to tell the browser to close the connection
header("Content-Length: $size");
header('Connection: close');

// flush all output
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
*/

Sleep(300); /* long work */
printInFile($result);
```

Естественно все таймауты стоят больше 300 секунд: httpd.conf (Timeout 600) и php.ini (max_execution_time = 600).
Беда в том, что до конца он никогда не выполняется. Если его выполнять, то получается ошибка через 3 минуты

> Script timed out before returning headers: php-cgi.exe

Это и логично, заголовки не шлются. Если слать закрытие соединения (откомментировать кусок), то  через 1 минуту ошибка

> (70007)The timeout specified has
> expired: [client 172.16.0.62:11997]
> AH00574: ap_content_length_filter:
> apr_bucket_read() failed

Как заставить его выполняться до конца? И откуда эти таймауты 1 и 3 минуты? И кто убивает CGI процесс? Спасибо всем за участие и ответы.